# GUI в Linux и xlib

Tags: linux, gui, xlib

Вот в этой теме: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361648/how-do-you-make-linux-guis/361674#361674

Вычитал следующее:

> The "native" interface for Linux & most other Unix-like OSs is Xlib,
> the lowest-level C API for X11.
>
> «Родным» интерфейсом для Linux и большинства других Unix-подобных ОС
> является Xlib, C API самого низкого уровня для X11.

Подскажите пожалуйста, что могло имеется ввиду под термином "native" в данном случае ?
Это именно API Linux, как API Windows или все таки что то другое ?

Comment: Слово "native" взято в кавычки, потому что в линуксе нет никакого по-настоящему нативного GUI, это просто самый популярный способ работы с графикой. Xlib — это самая обычная библиотека для работы с самым обычным протоколом X11, и она есть не только на линуксе — в Windows и macOS её тоже можно использовать, если достать её откуда-нибудь

Comment: Просто Х11 появился ещё где-то в 80-годы... И долгое время никакой альтернативы не было. Вот он и стал ощущаться, как  "native" .